# Using OpenFileDialogbox to load a new excel or access file into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, excel-interop, openfiledialog

[image]

I'm using menu strip "Load.." to import a new excel or access file into my datagridview and trying to load the new excel nor access file into my datagridview1. But for now i can only open the OpenFileDialog form when i run the program and when i clicked the file that i want to load the datagridview doesn't appear to be working to load the file.

Here is my code that i made by using reference on youtube and so on in Google search.

```
Private Sub LoadToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoadToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "This PC"
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open Files.."
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    DataGridView1(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: There is an OleDb provider specifically for Excel files. Are you familiar with ADO.net? That is what you can use to accomplish this. It is also used for Access files.

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing here is "associating" the file name to the grid view. It's not going to work like this.

You should create a datatable from the file and use it as a data source of the grid view.

It's explained here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=545&v=o2lzV9MKGBk&feature=emb_logo

Comment: What do you mean by "associating"? I don't believe that code will even compile so no associating is happening.

Comment: The link may be helpful; unfortunately is appears to be C#.

Comment: You need to put some effort my friend :) ! C# and VB.Net are almost identical. There are six lines of code. The first fourth lines just invert the variable declarations (for example : instead of [string constr = "bla bla"], you write [dim Constr as string = "bla bla"] the last two lines, just remove semicolon. Otherwise you can use any C#-VB.Net converter. Just google "convert c# to vb.net" you'll find a ton of converters

Comment: I code in both languages and the OP appears to be brand new to coding. Since he is starting vb.net that is the language he needs help in. What is simple to you might be very confusing to the OP.